# Unable to attach Debugger

Tags: java, netbeans, debian

I want to attach a debugger to see what runtime errors are being thrown by an app on github, [Mamute](https://github.com/caelum/mamute).  I can't attach my debugger in Netbeans.  I go to the top menu > Debugger > Attach Debugger > set my PID to 1234...Error:

> Operation not permitted

I saw a solution [online](http://echo%200%20%3E%20/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope) to run:

`echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`

I tried this and it does not work.  My Debian install has no `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/` directory.

Online the solution tends to be around turning off ptrace protection.  There's a bug on [Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712740) for this.

Comment: Have you tried running netbeans as root?

Comment: That did it.  `gksu /usr/bin/netbeans`.  You can add answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run netbeans as root

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: See question's comment, this is an answer